# Insert values into a table with values from another table MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using MS-Access 2013. I need to insert values into a table and some of the values in the table will be ID numbers from other tables. I will insert an IMEI number and then the next column will be an ID number from a different table. This ID number is from a table that holds all of the makes and models of different devices. The table looks like this:

```
ID Number  |     IMEI     |    Model ID
   1       |  1122334455  |      565
   2       |  2222555555  |      400
   3       |  9999944444  |      309
```

Where the Model table looks like:

```
Model ID   |    Make        |     Model
  565      |    Apple       |    iPhone 6
  400      |    Samsung     |    Galaxy S4
  309      |    HTC         |    One M8
```

There are a lot of makes and models so it is unrealistic for me to look up the Model ID for each insert.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
INSERT INTO Device (IMEI, [Model ID])
SELECT [Enter IMEI], [Model Table].[Model ID]
FROM [Model Table]
WHERE [Enter Make]=[Model Table].Make AND [Enter Model]=[Model Table].Model
```

This works as long as the Make and Model already exist. However, if they don't exist, the query won't insert. This where I am getting stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated or even a point in the right direction.

Comment: so, if the make and model don't exist, you only want to insert the IMEI without make and model?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Make/Model Exist, if so, insert IMEI and model, if not INSERT IMEI only

```
DECLARE @IMEI NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @MODEL NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @MAKE NVARCHAR(100)

SET @IMEI = '97658769'
SET @MAKE = NULL
SET @MODEL = NULL

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 from [Model Table] 
    WHERE [Model Table].Make = @MAKE
    AND [Model Table].Model = @MODEL
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Device (IMEI, [Model ID])
    VALUES (@IMEI, @MODEL)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Device (IMEI, [Model ID])
    VALUES (@IMEI, NULL)
END
```